# Moving text in textView android

Tags: android

I would like to ask you if textview has any option that when I have too long text for example text has 30 dp and textview has 15 dp I want to show text which is moving from left corner to right and return to start and again. Something like animation. I want to user see all text. Something like automatic scroll.

Edit: How I can do that in code, not xml?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use [`android:ellipsize="marquee"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize).

**EDIT:** you can use `textView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);`

Comment: nothing happened,results for me are same as android:singleLine="True"

Comment: @Ovidiu What I want to say is that does compile, but it does not move the text

Comment: Single-line text view that scrolls automatically if the text is too long to fit in the widget

Answer (score 14):

an example -

in the XML :

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:textColor="#ff4500"
        android:text="this is a very long piece of text that will move" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

in Java:

```
        tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tv);  
        tv.setSelected(true);  // Set focus to the textview
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/YOURID"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        />
```

This will help it to scroll until it is focused

Answer (score 2):

Use this code, it's working 100%:

```
TextView top=new TextView(this);
top.setText("Developers are working to add more features");
top.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
top.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
top.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
top.setFocusable(true);
top.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its called **marquee**. Set the following to your `TextView`:

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
```

Comment: setting `ellipsize` and `singleLine` only won't help, try other answers, you need to set `textview.setSelected(true);` as well in your code

Answer (score 0):

Try this 3 lines codes: (a summary of the above)

```
    textView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    textView.setSingleLine(true);
    textView.setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

**In order to move text, besides adding attributes:**

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:singleLine="true"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:focusable="true"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

it is necessary for View to be in focus, so this can be done in two ways:

1. Programmatically:

   ```
   tv.setSelected (true);
   ```
2. Do everything in XML by adding ***requestFocus*** tag:

   ```
   <TextView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true">
        <requestFocus />
   </TextView>
   ```